# How to convert xml to json in Groovy?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

In groovy I have the below xml

```
<data>
   <row>
      <id>USA</id>
      <value>United States of America</value>
   </row>
   <row>
      <id>CAN</id>
      <value>Canada</value>
   </row>
</data>
```

I need to transform the above xml in groovy to the below json format

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "KEY": "USA",
         "VALUE": "United States of America"
      },
      {
         "KEY": "CAN",
         "VALUE": "Canada"
      }
   ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Hari

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41073630/xml-to-json-conversion-in-groovy

Comment: what have you tried so far? what problems did you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
//Pass xml as string to below parseText method
def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
//Create the map as needed out of parsed xml
def map = [(parsed[0].name): parsed.'**'
  .findAll{it.name() == 'row'}
  .collect{ row ->
     row.collectEntries{[KEY: row.id.text(), VALUE:row.value.text()]}
   }
]
println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(map).toPrettyString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5110058471915520)</kbd>

Comment: Just nitpicking: you don't need the `row.collectEntries{ ... }` there - the `...` is enough